# Issue with Prefetch in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, prefetch

I have the current model in my Django app:

```
class Referentiel(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    libelle = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Reference(models.Model):
    referentiel = models.ForeignKey('Referentiel', related_name='reference_set')
    clef = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class ValeurReference(models.Model):
    reference = models.ForeignKey('Reference', related_name='valeur_set')
    valeur = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=5)
    date_fin = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

And I wish to retrieve values of a Referentiel, so I do something like that:

```
Referentiel.objects.filter(code='whatever_code').prefetch_related(Prefetch('reference_set__valeur_set', to_attr='valeurs'))
```

But I have the following error when trying to get my values:

```
AttributeError: 'Referentiel' object has no attribute 'valeurs'
```

Django version: 1.7.4
Python version: 3.4.2

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I tested some code and it seems that the 'valeurs' has been set inside the reference_set and not inside the Referentiel queryset. If you need all the ValeurReference you could use de values() method.

Comment: You mean "valeurs" in inside each "Reference" model instance into the `reference_set` of my queryset?

Comment: That´s it. If **referentiels** is a var with you queryset, you can print "valeurs" with:
`for a in referentiels:
for b in a.reference_set.all():
print b.valeurs`

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old question, but I encountered such error recently as well.

The problem is that `valeurs` are not assigned to `Referentiel` object, but to the `reference_set`.

So in this case, given that you have a queryset like this:

```py
queryset = (
    Referentiel
    .objects
    .filter(code='whatever_code')
    .prefetch_related(Prefetch('reference_set__valeur_set', to_attr='valeurs'))
)
```

Instead of doing:

```py
queryset[0].valeurs
```

You have to do:

```py
queryset[0].reference_set.all()[0].valeurs
```

Unfortunately the `to_attr` may be misleading and scenario with nested lookup is not mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have use the queryset parameter to specify the custom query for prefetch and from there prefetch valeur_set.

**Update:**

```
reference_qs = Reference.objects.prefetch('valeurreference_set').all()

    Referentiel.objects.filter(code='whatever_code')\
        .prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('reference_set', queryset=reference_qs, to_attr='valeurs')
        )
```

Comment: I see what you mean but how to do it in my example please?

Comment: This doesn't work. In this case the 'valuers' attribute will return Reference objects, not ValuerReference. I couldn't find a solution though